# Buttons On NEXTCORD

Tags: button, discord, command, nextcord

Why is this code not working ?The purpose of the code was to make the button work forever, because after a while, it stops working, can someone give me some naughty help? xD

```
@client.command()
async def teste(ctx, role : nextcord.Role):
    class buttons(nextcord.ui.View(timeout = 0)):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.value = None
        @nextcord.ui.button(label = "teste", style = nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
        async def teste(self, button : nextcord.ui.Button, interaction : nextcord.Interaction):
            if role in interaction.user.roles:
                await interaction.user.remove_roles(role)
            else:
                await interaction.user.add_roles(role)
    view = buttons()
    await ctx.send("teste", view = view)
    await view.wait()
```

Comment: is this your code, what have you tried and what is the broader context. The way you asked the question sounds like you did not take the time to read through the code and try to understand what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot build a class inside a command.

```
class buttons(nextcord.ui.View(timeout = 0)):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.value = None

        @nextcord.ui.button(label = "teste", style = nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
        async def teste(self, button : nextcord.ui.Button, interaction : nextcord.Interaction):
            if role in interaction.user.roles:
                await interaction.user.remove_roles(role)
            else:
                await interaction.user.add_roles(role)
```

Make sure to keep your class above the actual command. That way it works.

```
@client.command()
async def teste(ctx, role : nextcord.Role):
    view = buttons()
    await ctx.send("teste", view=view)
    await view.wait()
```